# How from switch to return result return?

Tags: c#

How from `switch` to return result `return`?
Method1, depending on the value of the variable "str_1", selects an additional method to execute.

I get an error:
"Using local variable" s1 ", which is not assigned a value."

**Code**

```
public string Method1(string str_1)
        {
            string s1;

            switch (str_1)
            {
                case "type_1":
                    s1 =  MethodTest();                    
                    break;
            }

            return s1;
        }


        public string MethodTest()
        {
            string s = "test";

            return s;
        }
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thats correct. Switch not necessarily will lead to use your one case you have.

There are need to be performed one of 2 changes:

1)

```
string s1 = string.Empty; //(provide default value)
```

2) provide:

```
switch (str_1)
{
  /*...*/
  default:
    s1 = "...";
    break;
```

Answer (score 2):

`string s1 = string.Empty` or `string s1 = null`

It is complaining that it's possible for that value to not be set since there isn't any guarantee that the switch-case statement will be hit.

Answer (score 2):

`s1` has the possibility to have never been set to a value. The error will go away if you while declaring your string, you set it equal to a default value:

```
string s1 = string.Empty;
```

Answer (score 1):

I see 4 options:

1) `string s1= string.Empty;`

2) `string s1= null;`

3) `string s1="";`

4) You can make a small refactor:

```
public string Method1(string str_1)
{
    switch (str_1)
    {
        case "type_1":
            return MethodTest();
        default:
            return string.Empty;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid local variable. Just decide what are you going to return in default case.

```
public string Method1(string str_1)
{
    switch (str_1)
    {
        case "type_1":
            return MethodTest();
        default:
            return null;
    }
}
```